# How do I remove extra height produced by hidden overflown child?

Tags: html, css, angular, sass, angular-material2

I have a parent grid container with 2 columns. In the first column, I have multiple panels which expands the height of the parent container if opened. In the second column, I have a component which expands more than the parent container's initial height.

What I want is for the second column to expand its height based on the height of the parent container.

It currently works however, it produces extra height and an empty space underneath my content.

I have tried giving the second column a fixed height instead of using `calc()`. Which works, space is removed but it no longer expands. I'm unsure what my other options are.

```
// .scss
.parent-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 60% 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 1rem;
}

.first-column {
  width: 1fr;
}

.second-column {
  width: 1fr;
  max-height: calc(100% - 400px);
  overflow: auto;
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
}
```

```html
// .html
<div class="parent-container">
  <form class="first-column">
    <!-- Angular Material Components -->
  </form>
  <div class="second-column">
    <product-demo></product-demo>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you have `max-height: calc(100% - 400px)`? Do you have an image or screenshot of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: `calc(100% - 400px)` is to have height of second column expand 400px less than full height of parent container. Leaving it at 100% makes all the contents of the second column visible. It feels like a terrible solution but it works :\